# providing different publicSigningKey enteries for QA and PROD

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

In the `application-descriptor.xml` file for my application I have specified the `publicSigningKey` for the Android build of my hybrid app.

But, the key I'm using for QA (which results from a debug build of the app), is different than the one that will be used in production (a release build for submission to the Play Store).

What is the best way to control the signing key for the different builds?
Ideally, I would have it read in from a file instead of being inline in the xml.

The `.wlapp` files are being built using the `app-builder` `ant` task from the v7.0 CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly create an Ant task that replaces the application-descriptor.xml file with another version of the file (for the required environment) before running the the app builder Ant task.

Comment: Yes, I can do that ... or a task that replaces the contents of the `publicSigningKey` value so as to avoid having to maintain 2 copies of the file. It's not ideal to be editing the file either, but it seems better than maintaining multiple copies.

It would be great to have a better way of templating, but it sounds like we'll have to deal with "working practices" not "best practices" for now :-)